# Type error when saving FormData when using Redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I've tried to save FormData(Javascript's standard API) using redux toolkit.

```
const initialState{
 myFile: FormData | null
}


const controllerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'controller',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    test: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
    }),
//...
```

It complains

`Types of property 'myFile' are incompatible. Type 'WritableDraft<FormData> | null' is not assignable to type 'FormData | null'`

I don't know why it complains exactly, but redux toolkit uses immerjs inside of it so seems it wraps FormData with WritableDraft.

The only solution what I've found is changing `FormData | null` to `any`

```
const initialState{
 myFile: any
}
```

But I want to use `FormData | null` as a type of myFile. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `FormData` a type that is somehow part of a generic of a function you are defining this in?

Comment: @phry Nope, it's just javascript's standard API see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData

Comment: Ah. I'd assume that these have some very complex properties that `immer` can't really work on, so really you'll have to cast that manually to `FormData`.

Comment: That aside: We generally advise against putting *anything* that is not a plain object into the store. Especially with something like this that will likely be mutated from the outside. Doing so will potentially break functionality of react-redux, some middlewares and the devtools.
See [the style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) for more information.
it would be best to just convert that by doing `Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())` or something similar.

Comment: Serializing is my plan B, now I should do this. thank you @phry